# Несколько вопросов по ВЕБ

Tags: php, html, localhost, сервер

Доброго времени суток! Хочу задать несколько вопросов:

1. Как легче всего можно скачать сайт из сервера? Сайт мой, сервер FTP.
2. Какие инструменты самые лучшие для редактирования сайта?
3. И самый важный вопрос: как правильно внести изменения с локалхоста на свой сервер, чтобы не было неполадок?

Буду ждать ответов.

Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Jakub, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

1. Зайти на фтп любым фтп-клиентом и скачать все файлы сайта + если используется база, то сделать дамп через пхпмайадмин.
2. Тут, скорее, каждый находит для себя, какой у него лучший редактор, отредактировать можно и в блокноте, я использую PHP Expert Editor и Notepad++, для меня хватает, но есть и более мощные программы, думаю, более опытные люди вам подскажут.
3. На локалхосте не использовать прямые ссылки на локалхост + при переносе не забыть изменить данные для подключения к базе.

Comment: Спвсибо, ещё имею вопрос к третьему пункту. Например сайт уже вложен в просторы интернета и его надо чутка подредактировать. Первым делом играюсь с локалхостом и как уже делаю правильные изменения то как их загрузить на сам сайт? просто заменить файл на сервере или зайти на серверный файл и там делать изменения?

Comment: зайдите через ФТП на сервер, скачайте один нужный файл, внесите правки на локалхосте, закачайте обратно файл через ФТП с заменой.    
ну и также не забывайте делать копии файлов, чтобы быстро откатиться в случае чего

Comment: Не за что )

Answer (score 0):

1. Для работы с ftp можно использовать total commander (платный) или filezilla (бесплатный).
2. Для меня удобнее всего PHP Storm.

По 3 пункту - лучше всего использовать систему контроля версий типа Git или Мercurial. Тогда процесс выглядит так:
Отредактировал файл на locallhost, занес изменения в репозиторий системы контроля версий, зашел на сервер и забрал изменения из репозитория.
Плюсы:
 - в случае проблем, можно откатить изменения за любой период;
 - можно посмотреть всю историю изменений.